# Register a file extension for all users

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-extension

Lets say, I belong to `Administrators` in Windows 10 and I want:

- I.
- All other existed users.
- Users not created yet.
- 

When anyone from the above list press "enter" on a PDF file, then PDF opened with SumatraPDF.

Until now:

I create a key `HKCR/.pdf` with default value `SumatraPDF`.

Then I create a key `HKCR/SumatraPDF/Shell/open/command` with default value `"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "%1"`

But it is not so easy.

There is some an annoying key in `HKCU/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExt` which makes things difficult.

Can anyone explain the logic of registering file extensions on Windows 10?

PS: Edge usually capture PDF file extension but not if you `deny write` for everyone.

Comment: Creating key `HKCR/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/FileExt/.pdf` without default value and set key permissions `everyone: read` make pdf work for current user. Not for others because this key belongs to `HKCR`.

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of clarifications:

1. The "annoying" key is not under `HKCR`, the path is:

   - `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`
2. `HKCR` is a virtual hive that combines entries from these two locations:

   - `HKCU\SOftware\Classes`
   - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`

   to present the combination of machine-wide and per-user association in effect for the logged in user.
3. If an Admin user creates a new key in regedit.exe under `HKCR`, it's created under:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes`

  If a standard user creates the same key, it's cfeated under:
- `HKCU\SOftware\Classes`

So to avoid confustion, read from `HKCR`, but write to `HKCU` or `HKLM`, depending on your intent.

---

As to the central question, creating the combination of:

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\<FileExt>`

  - with a default value of `<ProgID>`

*and*

- `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\<ProgID>`

  - with a default value that's displayed as the `FileType`, along with the necessary subkeys to define default actions, will create a machine-wide association that will be the default for new users as well as existing users *who've never over-ridden the default action for opening the file via `Open with >` and selecting `Always use this program...`or similar actions available through a file's `Properties` dialog.

It's that action that creates a `UserChoice` sbukey under:

- `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\<FileExt>`

and over-rides the default.

Unfortunately, (last tune I checked) there's an extra layer of protection that thwarts deleting or modifying the key *via script*, but it can still be interactivley deleted, even by a standard user, via `regedit.exe`.